# Skew bug when having a fixed background

Tags: css, sass

So i am following a course on Udemy, (learning some advanced css), and wanted to make a change to their solution. Basically, i want the background images of each section to be fixed, to create a nice parallax effect. Anyway, the code below is what i've written

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
   to right bottom,
   rgba($color-primary-light, 0.75),
   rgba($color-primary-dark, 0.75)),
   url("../img/nat-4.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top right;

transform: skewY(-7deg);

& > * {
  transform: skewY(7deg);
}
```

And it is creating this bug: When scrolling, the bottom edge of the container is visible at all times, and the content slides in from the bottom. So the parallelogram type background shape is getting wider as I scroll down, until it reaches its width and then looks good. Was wondering how to fix this. I've taken some screenshots to show what is happening.

[image]

[image]

If you need any HTML markup let me know.

Comment: we always need HMTL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by ditching the whole `skew` idea, and switching to using `clip-path` instead.